# How do I use get method to input values to form field with PHP

Tags: php, html

I have the following code snippet of my fields I have in my form:

```
       <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="E-mail Address" value="" name="username"></input>
```

This is what I have in my input field. Is there anybody who will tell me how to get input values to the field using a url? e.g https://mysite?username=ken and it will show "ken" in the input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML, add the input field like this:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['username']); ?>" />
```

Basically, the value attribute of the text field needs to be set to:

```
<?php echo $_GET['username']; ?>
```

The code right above this is how you would output a get variable in php whether you are putting it in a text field or not. 
To access get variables, always use:

```
$_GET['variable_name'];
```

Then you can assign it to variables or pass it as a function parameter.

**However, I strongly do not recommend passing sensitive information like usernames and passwords through GET variables. **

First off, users could change the URL hence changing the variable. They could also accidentally share the URL with someone and that could give someone else access to their account. I would recommend that you create a cookie on their machine that is set to a random ID, and then in a MySQL database, associate that ID with a username so that you know the user can't accidentally share their account or change their username through the URL.

Comment: @jakelouis While technically correct, this is absolutely horrible to do. This leaves your visitors open to XSS attacks and other client side injection (getting malicious scripts to run just by visiting a url). In addition, if you are doing this along with a password, you will be logging plain text username/password to the server access logs as the query string (get parameters) are logged with the request on the server, completely defeating the security provided by hashing passwords.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn i completely understand, am using id numbers generated from mysql database, so i think am good and am not using passwords, just email and generated codes for verification :)

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I updated the answer to include htmlspecialchars function. Also, before you left this comment I had already advised him of using GET parameters being a bad idea. I hope he changes it, but that is completely up to him and I have tried my best to warn him.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, make an isset in your php form input that can catch your ken variable from GET post, never forget the `method="get"` inside the form tag and if you are planning on submitting on the same page you can use `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` inside your form tag.. hope this helps, here is your code.. ^_^

```
    <form id="form" name="form" method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">


                            <fieldset>


                                <p>Input</p>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="text" name="nameoffield" id="nameoffield" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['ken'])){echo $_GET['ken'];} ?>"> <br />


                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                            <div>
                                <button type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
                                    Submit
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<input>` tag and other fields of form must be in a `<form>`tag.

```
<form action = "https://mysite" method = "get">
<input id = "username" type = "text" placeholder = "E-mail Address" name = "username" value = "<?php echo $_GET['username']; ?>" />
</form>
```

In the above code, form tag specifies that the **method** of submission is 'GET' and the **action** that will be taken on submission is URL to which your form data will be submitted and processed.

Now assuming that your `form` is in the same URL to which you are submitting your form, you will get the `GET` value in the same page (or URL), so in the input text field set the value which is obtained by GET method and use it.

All the GET key-value pairs are stored in an associative array $_GET from which you can access the value of a given key by using that as the index of the array.

e.g. Key is `username` in this case, so to get the value of the **username**, `$_GET['username']` was used.

Comment: Thanks, really helped alot!!